# PHP uploads image to Laravel controller, which reads it as a string?

Tags: php, laravel, image, eloquent, upload

In Laravel blade, I'm writing a form where certain users can add the details of a book to a database. The HTML is below: pay attention to the 'photo' section.

```
<form action="submitAdd" method="get" class="form-inline" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  @csrf
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="title ">Title: </label>
      <input type="text" name="title " >
    <label for="author">Author: </label>
      <input type="text" name="author">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="book_id">Book ID: </label>
      <input type="number" name="book_id">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="genre_id">Genre: </label>
      <select name="genre_id">
        <option name="Arts" value=1>Arts</option>
        <option name="Engineering" value=2>Engineering</option>
        <option name="Chemistry" value=3>Chemistry</option>
        <option name="Philosopy" value=4>Philosophy</option>
        <option name="Medicine" value=5>Medicine</option>
      </select>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="status_id">Status: </label>
      <select name="status_id">
        <option name="Available" value=1>Available</option>
        <option name="Requested" value=2>Requested</option>
        <option name="Unavailable" value=3>Unavailable</option>
        <option name="Alumni" value=4>Alumni</option>
      </select>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="photo">Photo: </label>
      <input type="file" name="photo" />
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add Book" />
  </div>
</form>
```

This invokes a controller's method, "AddBook", which is listed below

```
public function addBook(Request $request) {

    $genres = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
    $statuses = [1,2,3,4];

    $validated = Validator::make($request->all(), [
      "submit"    => "required",
      "book_id" => ["required", "integer", "regex:/^[0-9]+$/"],
      "title" => ["required", "regex: /^[a-zA-Z’'. -]+$/"],
      "author"   => ["required", "regex: /^[a-zA-Z’'. -]+$/"],
      "genre_id" => ["required", Rule::in([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]) ],
      "status_id" => ["required", Rule::in([1, 2, 3, 4]) ],
      "photo" => "required|image|file:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048"
    ]);

    $errors = $validated->errors();

    if($validated->fails()) {
      return redirect()->back()->withInput($request->all())->withErrors($errors);
    }

    $data = $request->all();
    $image = "";
    if ($request->hasFile("photo")) {
      echo "<h2>". $request->photo . "</h2>";
      $image = $request->file('photo');
      $new_name = rand() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension(); //CAUSES ERROR
      $image->move(public_path('photos'), $new_name);
    } else {
      echo "<h3>Request doesn't have photo</h3>";
    }
    try {
      $insert =
      DB::table('CCEAGpoc.dbo.Student')->insert([
        ['student_id'  => $data['student_id'],
        ‘title'    => $data['title'],
        'author'     => $data['author'],
        'genre_id'   => $data['genre_id'],
        'photo'       => $image, 
        'status_id'   => $data['status_id']]
      ]);
        return view ('submit/submitSuccess/addSuccess');//->with('message', $message);

    } catch (Exception $ex) { 
      return redirect()->back()->withInput($request->all())->withErrors($errors);
    }
  }
```

The above code works for everything except photos.

When I make a submission, I get the following validation failures:

"The photo must be an image.
The photo must be a file."

When I remove the photo validation, I get these errors instead:

```
"SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 20018 Implicit conversion from data type varchar to varbinary(max) is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query. [20018] (severity 16) [insert into [CCEAGpoc].[dbo].[Student] ([course_id], [forename], [photo], [status_id], [student_id], [surname]) values ('2', 'w', '', '3', '10000029', 'w')] (SQL: insert into [CCEAGpoc].[dbo].[Student] ([course_id], [forename], [photo], [status_id], [student_id], [surname]) values (2, w, , 3, 10000029, w))"
```

When I remove the if-check that executes the photo checking, I get this error:

```
Call to a member function getClientOriginalExtension() on null
```

For this line:

```
$new_name = rand() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
```

I've looked up the solutions to these errors, but they haven't helped me. What else should I be doing?

Comment: what do you get when you `dd($request->photo)`?

Comment: `‘title'` You have a non ascii single quote in there, have you been editing with a word processor by any chance?

Comment: @KevinRED Using POST, I get:
`  -test: false
  -originalName: "download.jpg"
  -mimeType: "image/jpeg"
  -error: 0
  #hashName: null
  path: "/tmp"
  filename: "php3MFlxr"
  basename: "php3MFlxr"
  pathname: "/tmp/php3MFlxr"
  extension: ""
  realPath: "/tmp/php3MFlxr"
  aTime: 2018-11-01 10:40:28
  mTime: 2018-11-01 10:40:27
  cTime: 2018-11-01 10:40:27
  inode: 393240
  size: 4813
  perms: 0100600
  owner: 1000
  group: 1000
  writable: false
  readable: false
  executable: false
  file: true
  dir: false
  link: false
}`
It fails in the DB insertion, however.

Comment: @RiggsFolly No, that's just how I prepared it for stackoverflow. The actual code doesn't have that quote

Answer (score 2):

You are using `GET` in the form method, you should be using `POST`.

Comment: That got me past the laravel validation, which I'm thankful for, but now I've gotten this error.
    "SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 20018 Implicit conversion from data type varchar to varbinary(max) is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query. [20018] (severity 16)"

Comment: That depends on how you're trying to store your data. I'm not really familiar with the varbinary data type, so try searching around SO or maybe post another question. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks @newUserName02. I'm storing it as a base64 image, if that's any help. There seems to be little about this online...